# My request to fetch all findMeetingTimes is only limited to 5 times using the graph library

Tags: laravel, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm developer a request to get all available times through /me/findMeetingTimes using microsoft graph

```
public function calendar(Request $request)
  {
   
   if($request->dia == ''){
     $dia = date('Y-m-d');
   }else{
    $dia = $request->dia;
   }
    $viewData = $this->loadViewData();

    $graph = $this->getGraph();

$bodyjson = '{
      "attendees": [
          {
              "emailAddress": {
                  "address": "'.$request->sala.'",
                  "name": "'.$request->sala.'"
              },
              "type": "Required"
          }
      ],
      "timeConstraint": {
         "activityDomain": "unrestricted",
          "timeslots": [
              {
                  "start": {
                      "dateTime": "'.$dia.'T08:00:00",
                      "timeZone": "'.$viewData['userTimeZone'].'",
                  },
                  "end": {
                      "dateTime": "'.$dia.'T19:00:00",
                      "timeZone": "'.$viewData['userTimeZone'].'",
                  }
              }
          ]
      },
      "locationConstraint": {
        "isRequired": "false",
        "suggestLocation": "false",
        "locations": [
            {
                "displayName": "Conf Room 32/1368",
                "locationEmailAddress": "email address removed for privacy reasons"
            }
        ]
      },
      "meetingDuration": "PT1H",
      "minimumAttendeePercentage": 100
  }';

    $getEventsUrl = '/me/findMeetingTimes';
    $events = $graph->createRequest('POST', $getEventsUrl)->attachBody($bodyjson)
      // Add the user's timezone to the Prefer header
      ->addHeaders(array(
        'Prefer' => 'outlook.timezone="'.$viewData['userTimeZone'].'"'
      ))
      ->setReturnType(Model\Event::class)
      ->execute();

      dd($events);

}
```

You can see that there is no limiter that sets a return of only 5 times, but still it return to me like this

```
 "meetingTimeSuggestions" => array:5 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▼
        "confidence" => 100.0
        "organizerAvailability" => "free"
        "attendeeAvailability" => array:1 [▶]
        "locations" => []
        "meetingTimeSlot" => array:2 [▼
          "start" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T08:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
          "end" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T09:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:5 [▼
        "confidence" => 100.0
        "organizerAvailability" => "free"
        "attendeeAvailability" => array:1 [▶]
        "locations" => []
        "meetingTimeSlot" => array:2 [▼
          "start" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T09:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
          "end" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T10:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      2 => array:5 [▼
        "confidence" => 100.0
        "organizerAvailability" => "free"
        "attendeeAvailability" => array:1 [▶]
        "locations" => []
        "meetingTimeSlot" => array:2 [▼
          "start" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T10:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
          "end" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T11:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      3 => array:5 [▼
        "confidence" => 100.0
        "organizerAvailability" => "free"
        "attendeeAvailability" => array:1 [▶]
        "locations" => []
        "meetingTimeSlot" => array:2 [▼
          "start" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T11:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
          "end" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T12:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      4 => array:5 [▼
        "confidence" => 100.0
        "organizerAvailability" => "free"
        "attendeeAvailability" => array:1 [▶]
        "locations" => []
        "meetingTimeSlot" => array:2 [▼
          "start" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T12:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
          "end" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T13:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

In the microsoft account of the "emailAddress" a time slot between 8:00 am and 5:00 pm was defined
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwRI7.png)

If I register a meeting at the last return time (12h00 to 13h00), in the next request it returns me
the next time not shown before (13:00 to 14:00)

```
"meetingTimeSuggestions" => array:5 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▼
        "confidence" => 100.0
        "organizerAvailability" => "free"
        "attendeeAvailability" => array:1 [▶]
        "locations" => []
        "meetingTimeSlot" => array:2 [▼
          "start" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T08:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
          "end" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T09:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      1 => array:5 [▼
        "confidence" => 100.0
        "organizerAvailability" => "free"
        "attendeeAvailability" => array:1 [▶]
        "locations" => []
        "meetingTimeSlot" => array:2 [▼
          "start" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T09:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
          "end" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T10:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      2 => array:5 [▼
        "confidence" => 100.0
        "organizerAvailability" => "free"
        "attendeeAvailability" => array:1 [▶]
        "locations" => []
        "meetingTimeSlot" => array:2 [▼
          "start" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T10:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
          "end" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T11:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      3 => array:5 [▼
        "confidence" => 100.0
        "organizerAvailability" => "free"
        "attendeeAvailability" => array:1 [▶]
        "locations" => []
        "meetingTimeSlot" => array:2 [▼
          "start" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T11:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
          "end" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T12:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
        ]
      ]
      4 => array:5 [▼
        "confidence" => 100.0
        "organizerAvailability" => "free"
        "attendeeAvailability" => array:1 [▶]
        "locations" => []
        "meetingTimeSlot" => array:2 [▼
          "start" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T13:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
          "end" => array:2 [▼
            "dateTime" => "2023-05-17T14:00:00.0000000"
            "timeZone" => "E. South America Standard Time"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Is there any limiter that does not allow the return to have more than 5 times, any suggestions of what this could be?

Is there any limiter that does not allow the return to have more than 5 times, any suggestions of what this could be?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/rate-limiting

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).